# Запуская кода с расширением .pyw программа работает безотказно, а запуская тот же файл с тем же расширением с рабочего стола перестает работать

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, visual-studio-code, app

Пишу программу для WhatsApp-рассылки сообщений на python с использованием библиотеки PyQt5. Пишу в текстовом редакторе VSCode. Создал главное окно с менюбаром и парой функций, и, если запускать код из редактора, всё работает безотказно. Решил проверить работу программы, если запустить файл с рабочего стола. Поменял расширение главного файла с .py на .pyw, запустил программку, открылось главное меню, все работало как надо. Но, как только решил проверить работу основных функций, а именно работу рассылки и добавления людей в базу данных (папку с файлами, в которых хранится информация о клиентах), ничего не запустилось, а программа перестала работать. Опять же повторюсь, если запустить тот же самый файл из Visual Studio, такая проблема исчезает сразу и всё работает как часы.

Код файлов:

main.py

```
from main_window import *
import sys

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

main_window.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from functions import send_message, create_new_file


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi()


    def setupUi(self):
        '''settings of window'''
        
        #settings of main window
        self.setWindowTitle("Расслыка")
        self.move(300, 300)
        self.resize(600, 500)

        #settings of menubar
        menuBar = self.menuBar()

        self.distAllMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&Рассылка")
        self.distAllMenu.addAction("Разослать всем", self.action_clicked)
        self.distAllMenu.addAction("Разослать выборочно", self.action_clicked)

        self.dataBaseMenu = menuBar.addMenu("&База данных")
        self.dataBaseMenu.addAction("Добавить клинта", self.action_clicked)
        self.dataBaseMenu.addAction("Удалить клиента", self.action_clicked)
        self.dataBaseMenu.addAction("Очистить всё", self.action_clicked)

        self.setupui_widgets_add_client()

        
    def setupui_widgets_add_client(self):
        '''This method incloods all elements to form "Add client".
           Function "hide_widgets" hides these elements from main_window'''

        #text field to input name
        self.txt_name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.txt_name.resize(200, 50)
        self.txt_name.move(10, 50)
        self.txt_name.setText("Имя")
        self.txt_name.setStyleSheet('font-size:12pt; font-family: caption;')

        #text field to input second name
        self.txt_second_name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.txt_second_name.resize(200, 50)
        self.txt_second_name.move(10, 110)
        self.txt_second_name.setText("Фамилия")
        self.txt_second_name.setStyleSheet('font-size:12pt; font-family: caption;')

        #text field to input father name
        self.txt_father_name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.txt_father_name.resize(200, 50)
        self.txt_father_name.move(10, 170)
        self.txt_father_name.setText("Отчество")
        self.txt_father_name.setStyleSheet('font-size:12pt; font-family: caption;')

        #text field to input phone number
        self.txt_phone_number = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.txt_phone_number.resize(200, 50)
        self.txt_phone_number.move(390, 50)
        self.txt_phone_number.setText("+7")
        self.txt_phone_number.setStyleSheet('font-size:12pt; font-family: caption;')

        #combobox to choice seats type
        self.cm_seat = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.cm_seat.resize(200, 50)
        self.cm_seat.move(390, 110)
        self.cm_seat.addItem("Диван")
        self.cm_seat.addItem("Кресло")
        self.cm_seat.addItem("Стул")
        self.cm_seat.setStyleSheet('font-size:12pt; font-family: caption;')

        #text field to input number of seat
        self.txt_seats_number = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.txt_seats_number.resize(200, 50)
        self.txt_seats_number.move(390, 170)
        self.txt_seats_number.setText("Номер места")
        self.txt_seats_number.setStyleSheet('font-size:12pt; font-family: caption;')

        #label, that informs about created file in DataBase
        self.lbl_clien_added = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.lbl_clien_added.setText("")
        self.lbl_clien_added.resize(300, 50)
        self.lbl_clien_added.move(170, 300) 
        self.lbl_clien_added.setStyleSheet('font-size:10pt; font-family: caption;')

        #button to add client in DataBase
        self.btn_add_client = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn_add_client.setText("Добавить клиента")
        self.btn_add_client.resize(200, 50)
        self.btn_add_client.move(10, 440)
        self.btn_add_client.clicked.connect(self.get_datas)

        #button to close all "add client" widgets
        self.btn_exit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.btn_exit.setText("Закрыть")
        self.btn_exit.resize(200, 50)
        self.btn_exit.move(390, 440)
        self.btn_exit.clicked.connect(self.hide_widgets)


        self.hide_widgets()


    def hide_widgets(self):
        '''This method incloods all elements from all menu actions
                          and hides them.'''

        self.txt_name.hide()
        self.txt_second_name.hide()
        self.txt_father_name.hide()
        self.txt_phone_number.hide()
        self.cm_seat.hide()
        self.txt_seats_number.hide()
        self.lbl_clien_added.hide()
        self.btn_add_client.hide()
        self.btn_exit.hide()

    
    def show_widgets_add_client(self):
        """This method incloods all elements from action "add client"
                          and shows them."""

        self.txt_name.show()
        self.txt_second_name.show()
        self.txt_father_name.show()
        self.txt_phone_number.show()
        self.cm_seat.show()
        self.txt_seats_number.show()
        self.lbl_clien_added.show()
        self.btn_add_client.show()
        self.btn_exit.show()


    def get_datas(self):
        '''The method gets datas from "add client form"'''

        name = self.txt_name.text()
        second_name = self.txt_second_name.text()
        father_name = self.txt_father_name.text()
        phone_no = self.txt_phone_number.text()
        type_seat = self.cm_seat.currentText()
        seat_num = self.txt_seats_number.text()

        create_new_file(name, second_name, father_name, phone_no, type_seat, seat_num)
        self.lbl_clien_added.setText(f"Файл \"{name} {father_name}.txt\" создан!")


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def action_clicked(self):
        '''performs actions from menuBar'''

        action = self.sender()
        
        if action.text() == "Разослать всем":
            send_message()
        elif action.text() == "Добавить клинта":
            self.show_widgets_add_client()
```

functions.py

```
import os
import time
import mouse

import webbrowser as web
from urllib.parse import quote
import pyautogui as pg


def create_new_file(name = str, 
                    second_name = str,
                    father_name = str,
                    phone_number = str, 
                    type_of_seats = str, 
                    seats = str):
    """Function creating new file in DataBase"""


    file_name = second_name + ' ' + name    #name for new file
    
    #text in new file
    text = 'Имя: ' + name + '\n'
    text += 'Фамилия: ' + second_name + '\n'
    text += 'Отчество: ' + father_name + '\n'
    text += 'Номер телефона: ' + phone_number + '\n'
    text += 'Тип мест: ' + type_of_seats + '\n'
    text += 'Номера мест: ' + seats
    
    with open('DataBase\\' + file_name + '.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
            file.write(text)
    

def data_request():
    '''The function requests datas and call function 
                "create_new_file" '''

    
    #form for datas
    name = input('\nИмя: ')
    second_name = input('Фамилия: ')
    father_name = input('Отчество: ')
    phone_number = input('Номер телефона: ')
    type_of_seats = input('Тип мест: ')
    seats = input('Номера мест: ')

    create_new_file(name, second_name, father_name, phone_number, type_of_seats, seats)


def close_brouser():
    '''The function closes brouser by mooving cursor'''

    
    #Coordinets of screen to click 'close'
    mouse_pos_close_x = 1900
    mouse_pos_close_y = 10
    
    #Coordinates of screen to agree close screen
    mouse_pos_close_yes_x = 765
    mouse_pos_close_yes_y = 175

    mouse.move(mouse_pos_close_x, mouse_pos_close_y, absolute = True, duration = 0.1)
    mouse.click('left')
    mouse.move(mouse_pos_close_yes_x, mouse_pos_close_yes_y, absolute = True, duration= 0.1)
    mouse.click('left')


def open_whatsapp_and_send_message(phone_number = str, message = str):
    '''This function opens whatsapp and sends message automatically'''


    web.open(f"https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={phone_number}&text={quote(message)}")
    time.sleep(8)
    pg.press("enter")
    

def send_message(date = 'завтра'):
    '''Main function for sending massege to client in whatsapp'''
    
    
    clients = parser() #[[имя, отчество, телефон], [], []...]

    for client in clients:
        text = 'Добрый вечер, ' + client[0] + ' ' + client[1] + '!\n'
        text += 'Мы рады сообщить, что уже ' + date + ' состоится наш концерт!\n'
        text += 'Будем счастливы видеть вас на нём!'

        open_whatsapp_and_send_message(client[2], text)
        time.sleep(1)
        close_brouser()
        time.sleep(2)


def pathes_to_files():
    '''Create pathes to files in DataBase'''

    #get all files names in DataBase
    all_files = os.listdir('DataBase')
    pathes = []

    #create path to every file and add it to "pathes"-arey
    for i in all_files:
        pathes.append('DataBase\\' + i)

    return pathes


def parser():
    '''Check every file in DataBase and get needed datas'''

    
    pathes = pathes_to_files()
    words_to_check = ('Имя: ', 'Отчество: ', 'Номер телефона: ')

    datas = [] #[[имя, отчество, телефон], [], []...]
    
    #open every file in DataBase
    for i in pathes:
        with open(i, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
            
            needed_info = []
            
            for line in file:
                for word in words_to_check:
                    if word in line:
                        needed_info.append(line.replace(word, '').replace('\n', ''))

            datas.append(needed_info)
    
    return datas
```

Везде указаны относительные пути к папке "DataBase".
Буду очень признателен, если поможете, так как я сам пока что совсем только новичок в программировании и не понимаю, в чём проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно поменять рабочую директорию перед импортом. Проще всего создать ярлык ‘py путь/файл.pyw‘ и указать её в ярлыке.

Comment: Понял, попробую, спасибо!!

Comment: Можно проголосовать за ответ, это будет спасибо.